# OperaProfile object and Selenium RC (C#)

Tags: c#, opera, selenium-rc

I'm try to use selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar with opera and need to change some profile preferences.
It possible to create OperaProfile object in C# project and using it like this:

```
OperaProfile profile = new OperaProfile(); // Error: Type or namespace 'OperaProfile' could not be found
profile.preferences().set("User Prefs", "Ignore Unrequested Popups", false);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
capabilities.SetCapability("opera.profile", profile);
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://host:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

In this case I got error message

> *Type or namespace 'OperaProfile' could not be found*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows:

The Operadriver is written in Java and not suported directly in C#, as it is mainatined not by the Selenium project team but by Opera.

To use it, you have to run the standalone Selenium webserver (from console on windows) before starting the test.  [get it here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar)

you need to set the OPERA_PATH to point to your opera.exe file. Start the server with the command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
```

i use a small bat for these two tasks:

```
SET OPERA_PATH="C:\Progra~2\Opera\opera.exe"
cd C:\pathToSeleniumJarFile
C:\Progra~2\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
```

C#:
testing with remotewebdriver object in your C# code to connect to it.

```
        switch (WebBrowser)
        {
            case Browser.Chrome:
                // chromedriver.exe has to be in the debug folder
                ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
                chrome.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chrome);
                break;

            ...

            case Browser.Opera:
                //note: set OPERA_PATH environment variable (in cmd or global)
                DesiredCapabilities opera = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
                opera.SetCapability("opera.profile", @"C:\OperaProfile");
                webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(opera);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
```

if you want to manipulate the profile of the opera client (e.g. to accept untrusted certificates etc) you need to set

```
opera.SetCapability("opera.profile", @"C:\OperaProfile");
```

Copy an existing Profile to a location of your choice, here C:\OperaProfile.

==> Avoid spaces in all the pathes <==