# How to disable geolocation in Opera with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, opera

world!

Need help!
Selenium, C#, Opera48.
How to disble geolocation in Opera when test is run?

```
case browser_Opera:
OperaDriverService service = 
OperaDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C://Windows/"); //path to 
OperaDriver
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C://Program Files/Opera/launcher.exe"; //path to 
my Opera browser                                                         

//not working                                        
options.AddUserProfilePreference("Enable geolocation", 
false);
options.AddLocalStatePreference("Enable geolocation", false);

driver = new OperaDriver(service, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is set by `OperaProfile`

```
OperaProfile profile = new OperaProfile();
profile.preferences().set("Geolocation", "Enable geolocation", false);
driver = new OperaDriver(profile);
```

Reference: https://books.google.com/books?id=P7vNBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=opera+driver+options+geolocation&source=bl&ots=tWvTAQG03C&sig=JTRzgt58oUlU-buHmUvzsukYD2w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU4Jnv9MrWAhVB-mMKHTpeC8kQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=opera%20driver%20options%20geolocation&f=true

Comment: Thanks, good advice. But I tried to use it earlier and it's not work in my project, because OperaProfile "could not be found"

Comment: I see, then this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009695/operaprofile-object-and-selenium-rc-c .

Comment: Yeah. But there enable to use only capability. I have options and service either, and they need to start Opera and OperaDriver
--
driver = new OperaDriver(service, options);

Answer (score 0):

I found solution!!!!!!!!

```
OperaDriverService service = 
OperaDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\OperaProfile\"); 
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe"; 
options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=C:\OperaProfile\");

driver = new OperaDriver(service, options);
```

Comment: Congrats! But I don't see how the geolocation is set in your example?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Opera;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Udemyvericekme
{
    public partial class opera : Form
    {
        public opera()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
        OperaDriver drv;
        private void opera_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2);
            drv = new OperaDriver(options);
            drv.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

The code that disables geographic location in Opera

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2);
```